# How to retrieve all databases from azure subscription via foreach loop and stack in variable

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-5.0

I have the following which works fine to extract a list of all databases based no RESOURCE GROUP and store into a variable called $resources

```
$resources = Get-AzureRmResource | ?{ $_.ResourceGroupName -eq "resourceGROUPnameHERE" -and $_.kind -eq "v12.0,user"  } | select resourcename,resourceid
```

and output looks like the following (in two columns per resourcename nad resourceID)

```
ResourceName              ResourceId
------------              ----------
georgidbserver1/georgiDB1 /subscriptions/aaaaaa-bbbb-486a-96cf-6c68361d8000/resourceGroups/georgigroup/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/georgidbserver1/databases/georgiDB1
georgidbserver1/georgiDB2 /subscriptions/aaaaaa-bbbb-486a-96cf-6c68361d8000/resourceGroups/georgigroup/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/georgidbserver1/databases/georgiDB2
```

What I am looking to achieve , is to get the same output and store it the same way into a variable but NOT for a single recourse group , instead I want it to check all resource groups from my subscription and pull all databases from them in the list.

I created the following code that outputs exactly what I need in the powershell window

CODE is

```
$rg = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | ?{ $_.ProvisioningState -eq "succeeded" } | select -expandproperty resourcegroupname
foreach ($resourcegroup in $rg) {Get-AzureRmResource | ?{ $_.ResourceGroupName -eq $resourcegroup -and $_.kind -eq "v12.0,user"  } | select resourcename,resourceid}
```

Output looks like this (exactly how I want it)

PS C:\Users> .\small.ps1

```
ResourceName              ResourceId
------------              ----------
georgidbserver2/georgiDB3 /subscriptions/17e1cc9e-4eb3-486a-96cf-6c68361d8000/resourceGroups/dbgroup/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/georgidbserver2/databases/georgiDB3
georgidbserver2/georgiDB4 /subscriptions/17e1cc9e-4eb3-486a-96cf-6c68361d8000/resourceGroups/dbgroup/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/georgidbserver2/databases/georgiDB4
georgidbserver1/georgiDB1 /subscriptions/17e1cc9e-4eb3-486a-96cf-6c68361d8000/resourceGroups/georgigroup/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/georgidbserver1/databases/georgiDB1
georgidbserver1/georgiDB2 /subscriptions/17e1cc9e-4eb3-486a-96cf-6c68361d8000/resourceGroups/georgigroup/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/georgidbserver1/databases/georgiDB2
```

My question is how can I store the output of the second code that yields 4 rows into a variable just like it works in the first example for $resources.

I want to be able to loop through it later and create DB alerts for all databases in the subscription.I already have the code for alert creation for all DBs per resource group.Here I am looking to achieve the same but for all DBs in the subscription

Below,for reference, is the complete code that I use to create DB alerts per resource group

```
<#create CPU,DTU and Storage alerts for as many databases as you have in the resource group provided by keyboard input#>

#define variable for resource group name by requesting keyboard input

$rg = Read-Host 'Please, input resource group name here (exactly as it is in Azure)'

<#create the array containing databases where alerts are required. The value of v12.0,user corresponds to the kind of resource as to include only the SQL DBs and not the SQL servers#>

$resources = Get-AzureRmResource | ?{ $_.ResourceGroupName -eq $rg -and $_.kind -eq "v12.0,user"  } | select resourcename,resourceid

#loop through the array and create the DTU alert rule for each DB

foreach($resource in $resources){$alertname=$resource.resourcename.Substring($resource.resourcename.IndexOf('/')+1)+"-DTU-Alert";Add-AzureRMMetricAlertRule -ResourceGroup $rg -location "centralus" -targetresourceid $resource.resourceid -Name $alertname -MetricName "dtu_consumption_percent" -Operator "GreaterThan" -Threshold 90 -WindowSize $([TimeSpan]::Parse("00:15:00")) -TimeAggregationOperator "Average" -verbose -Actions $(New-AzureRmAlertRuleEmail -SendToServiceOwners -CustomEmails "Client-email@here")}

#loop through the array and create the CPU alert rule for each DB

foreach($resource in $resources){$alertname=$resource.resourcename.Substring($resource.resourcename.IndexOf('/')+1)+"-CPU-Alert";Add-AzureRMMetricAlertRule -ResourceGroup $rg -location "centralus" -targetresourceid $resource.resourceid -Name $alertname -MetricName "cpu_percent" -Operator "GreaterThan" -Threshold 90 -WindowSize $([TimeSpan]::Parse("00:15:00")) -TimeAggregationOperator "Average" -verbose -Actions $(New-AzureRmAlertRuleEmail -SendToServiceOwners -CustomEmails "Client-email@here")}

#loop through the array and create the STORAGE alert rule for each DB

foreach($resource in $resources){$alertname=$resource.resourcename.Substring($resource.resourcename.IndexOf('/')+1)+"-STORAGE-Alert";Add-AzureRMMetricAlertRule -ResourceGroup $rg -location "centralus" -targetresourceid $resource.resourceid -Name $alertname -MetricName "storage_percent" -Operator "GreaterThan" -Threshold 90 -WindowSize $([TimeSpan]::Parse("00:15:00")) -TimeAggregationOperator "Average" -verbose -Actions $(New-AzureRmAlertRuleEmail -SendToServiceOwners -CustomEmails "Client-email@here")}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a nested loops. The following script works for me.

```
$rg = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | ?{ $_.ProvisioningState -eq "succeeded" } | select -expandproperty resourcegroupname
foreach ($resourcegroup in $rg) 
{
    $resources = Get-AzureRmResource | ?{ $_.ResourceGroupName -eq $resourcegroup -and $_.kind -eq "v12.0,user"  } | select resourcename,resourceid,location
    foreach ($resource in $resources)
    {
        ##create the DTU alert rule for each DB
        $alertname = $resource.resourcename.Substring($resource.resourcename.IndexOf('/')+1)+"-DTU-Alert"
        Add-AzureRMMetricAlertRule -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup  -Location $resource.location -targetresourceid $resource.resourceid -Name $alertname -MetricName "dtu_consumption_percent" -Operator "GreaterThan" -Threshold 90 -WindowSize $([TimeSpan]::Parse("00:15:00")) -TimeAggregationOperator "Average" -verbose -Actions $(New-AzureRmAlertRuleEmail -SendToServiceOwners -CustomEmails "test@hotmail.com")

        ##create the CPU alert rule for each DB
        $alertname=$resource.resourcename.Substring($resource.resourcename.IndexOf('/')+1)+"-CPU-Alert"
        Add-AzureRMMetricAlertRule -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup  -Location $resource.location -targetresourceid $resource.resourceid -Name $alertname -MetricName "cpu_percent" -Operator "GreaterThan" -Threshold 90 -WindowSize $([TimeSpan]::Parse("00:15:00")) -TimeAggregationOperator "Average" -verbose -Actions $(New-AzureRmAlertRuleEmail -SendToServiceOwners -CustomEmails "test@hotmail.com")

        ##create the STORAGE alert rule for each DB
        $alertname=$resource.resourcename.Substring($resource.resourcename.IndexOf('/')+1)+"-STORAGE-Alert"
        Add-AzureRMMetricAlertRule -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup  -Location $resource.location -targetresourceid $resource.resourceid -Name $alertname -MetricName "storage_percent" -Operator "GreaterThan" -Threshold 90 -WindowSize $([TimeSpan]::Parse("00:15:00")) -TimeAggregationOperator "Average" -verbose -Actions $(New-AzureRmAlertRuleEmail -SendToServiceOwners -CustomEmails "test@hotmail.com")
    }
}
```